YA sci fi book, tower on a planet with a destructive wind
Looking for the title of a book. Young adult sci fi.
Plot I remember involves a guy who's some kind of super soldier landing on a planet (he's after a bad guy). The planet experiences a destructive wind (which is coming soon obvs) guy climbs a huge tower to fight bad guy. He's really small, but in a massive golden suit. Wind comes, tower collapses (?)
Any ideas?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

This is Day of the Starwind, third (published - fourth in universe chronologically) in the Last Legionary series by Douglas Hill.
The super soldier is Keill Randor, the titular last Legionary of the destroyed planet Moros. The enemy is 'The One', a stunted, grey-skinned individual in a golden exo-suit which makes him exceptionally strong.
One of the key plot points in the series is that Keill earlier had his skeleton replaced with an unbreakable alloy - he can be hurt, but cam never break a bone.
Taking the summary from Wikipedia:

Keill and Glr are sent by the Overseers to investigate the planet
Jitrell, which has been plagued by a series of violent crimes, carried
out by highly trained combatants. His investigations take him to a
nearby planet Rilyn which is periodically orbited by the moon
Qualthorn, also known as "The Intruder", and the close proximity of
the moon causes planet-wide storms, called the Starwind, strong enough
to destroy and flatten anything on the surface - all native life is
subterranean. Glr is uncomfortable on the planet - the starwind when
it arrives will kill her, but she is unable to stay under cover as
being an avian species she has a fear of being underground. Together
they find a tall tower, many storeys high protected by an energy field
which nullifies all energy sources - including weapons and vehicle
power sources. He also comes into contact with a poorly trained group
of Jitrellian militia, also sent to investigate the planet. Obliged by
his moral code he assists them, however they are all killed - except
for their leader Tam - by a group of the combatants Keill has been
searching for. Keill recognises the faces of several soldiers and as
there are duplicate faces comes to the conclusion that they are clones
of long-dead legionaries. The strike team are eager to try their
skills against a real Legionary, but when given the chance, Keill
defeats them and makes his way into the tower. He meets their leader,
a golden cyborg calling himself Altern, who explains that the cloning
process has been going on for many years, that the forcefield will
easily withstand the Starwind, and even offers Keill a place in "The
legions of Rilyn" - as Keill has now killed the previous Strike Team
Leader.


This series comes up a lot:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Last+Legionary
